# Android Toast like pop up

Tags: android, message, toast

I've been using Toast but does android have anything similar to it but the message stays on display until the user closes it him/herself?

Comment: Use AlertDialog then.

Answer (score 2):

as per my knowledge you have three options to do this task.

1. Custome Toast
2. PopupWindow
3. SnackBar

   **CostumeToast**

   ```
     void errortoast(String Msg) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));

   TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);

   text.setText(Msg);

   Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

   toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | 0, 0, 0);

   toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

   toast.setView(layout);

   toast.show();

   }
   ```

**toast.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textToShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
    android:text="Error"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:textSize="19sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**PopUpWindow**

```
    public void displaypopup() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
}
```

**popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lytpopup"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvmessagedialogtitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Hello" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bmessageDialogYes"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#cb4c4c"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="View"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#77aa5c"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For more information [read](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

3. **snackbar**

for snackbar try [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-snackbar-example/) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dialog.
Read this page. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try Android Crouton :

[Android Croutons](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/)

[Github Link](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

Crouton is a class that can be used by Android developers that feel the need for an alternative to the Context insensitive Toast.

A Crouton will be displayed at the position the developer decides. Standard will be the top of an application window. You can line up multiple Croutons for display, that will be shown one after another.